# XStream entity abbrieviation parsing

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm currently trying to parse the Japanese JMdict xml document and it declares a bunch of `ENTITY` references that are used throughout the document.
Like this bit here:

```
<!ENTITY MA "martial arts term">
<!ENTITY X "rude or X-rated term (not displayed in educational software)">
<!ENTITY abbr "abbreviation">
<!ENTITY adj-i "adjective (keiyoushi)">
<!ENTITY adj-ix "adjective (keiyoushi) - yoi/ii class">
```

There are then referenced in the xml like so `<field>&MA;</field>`

XStream does not like this and demands that I fix this and then promptly throws a `ConversionException` and quits.

Is there a way to automatically recognize these entities and swap them out?
I'd prefer not having to write 170 lines of `xml = xml.replace(one, other);`

I'm just using XPP3 and then annotations to create POJOs from the data to begin with. No custom parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you're using XPP3, I assume that you are creating your XStream object like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();  //uses XPP3
```

The problem is that XPP3 apparently [does not resolve entities](http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/doc/api/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#ENTITY_REF) out of the box:

> ...it is user responsibility to resolve entity reference.

So unless you want to implement entity resolution, you need to use a parser that does resolve entities.  If you want to stay with a pull parser, you can use [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
```

Alternatively you could use [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (not a pull parser; loads the entire document into memory):

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
```